# mongodb and php: connection pooling

Tags: php, mongodb, connection-pooling

I'm using the native driver in PHP to connect to a mongo DB.

I don't understand the concept of connection pooling: is this like a 'pool' of connections, and when a user opens the website, a connection is pulled from this pool and used?

But what if you have multiple pages with some code that uses a mongoDB? Will the system pull a new connection from the pool every time the user changes the page?

In general: how can I manage this 'connection pool' (or is it managed automatically) when there are a lot of simultaneous connections?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't understand the concept of connection pooling: is this like a 'pool' of connections, and when a user opens the website, a connection is pulled from this pool and used?

Yes, that's exactly what it is.

> But what if you have multiple pages with some code that uses a mongoDB? Will the system pull a new connection from the pool every time the user changes the page?

Yes. The connection is taken from the pool when required (a user loads a page), and then returned to the pool when the script ends. It is persistent by default (set via the `mongo.allow_persistent` php.ini setting) and automatically handled by the driver.

> In general: how can I manage this 'connection pool' (or is it managed automatically) when there are a lot of simultaneous connections?

Connection pools are mostly managed automatically. You have some level of control using the [MongoPool](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongopool.php) class.